# Assign different continuous color gradients based on two different variables in ggplot2 in x and y direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R (and stack overflow) and would appreciate any help! I haven't been able to find a solution from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706390/varying-gradient-using-ggplot2-in-r) questions. I'm trying to:

1. Assign 2 different continuous color gradients in the x and y direction based on different variables. (plot1 in code below)
2. Retain these color assignments for a different plot of different variables of the same data frame. (plot2 in code below)

I have only been able to manage assigning color based on one variable as shown below.

Example:

```
####set up data####
#using ggplot2 package
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
                 c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 c(256, 4, 196, 16, 144, 36, 100, 64, 81, 49, 121, 25, 169, 9, 225, 1),
                 c(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610))
colnames(df) <- c("X", "Y", "V1", "V2")

####plot1: Simple plot of V1 vs V2#####
 #I would like the color to go towards blue as V1 increases on x axis (as it is now)
 #I would also like the color to go towards red as V2 increases on y axis
 #Ideally, when both x and y are large, it would be some purple color

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=V1, y = V2, color= V1)) + geom_point()+ 
  scale_color_continuous(low="black", high="light blue")+ 
  labs(y= "V2: I want this to go from black --> red", x = "V1: black--> blue")
plot1

####plot2: plot of x vs y but with color assignment same as plot1####
#The position based on X and Y is correct but,
#   I'd like to have the color assigned based on V1 and V2 (same as plot1)
plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=V1)) + geom_point()+
  scale_color_continuous(low="black", high="light blue")
plot2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a modification scoa's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279570/assign-point-color-depending-on-data-frame-column-value-r), maybe this will do the trick. You may have to manually build your legends though, as this approach makes the default legend unappealing.

With your data above:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
                 Y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 V1 = c(256, 4, 196, 16, 144, 36, 100, 64, 81, 49, 121, 25, 169, 9, 225, 1),
                 V2 = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610))
```

First, scale your `V1` and `V2` values to a max R and B values for an RGB color:

```
xcol <- df$V1 / max(df$V1) 
ycol <- df$V2 / max(df$V2)
```

Now, make a named color vector using `rgb()` and the scaled values:

```
col <- rgb(ycol, 0, xcol)
names(col) <- as.character(df$V1)
```

Now you can plot, passing `V1` as a factor to the `color` argument:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = as.factor(V1))) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

And for the second plot, keep the color arguments the same:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=as.factor(V1))) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. For anyone referencing this in the future, I was able to apply it to my much larger data set. I had to switch the column I assigned the color by to my equivalent of V2 for some reason... maybe because it has a much larger scale than the V1 in my data set.